# Group of $2 \times 2$ matrices with complex numbers

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be the smallest group of $2 \times 2$ matrices whose entries are complex numbers which contains both matrices
$$\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix} \quad \text{ and } \quad \begin{bmatrix}i&0\\0&-i\end{bmatrix},$$
where the complex number $i$ satisﬁes $i^2 = −1$ and where the binary operation is matrix multiplication. Determine all conjugacy classes of $G$.

Any ideas?

I had the idea of multiplying the matrices together, and finding the inverses of the matrices for the elements of the group, but feel like this wouldn't be helpful, and may make things more difficult for me
matrices.

Comment: What have you tried? What are your thoughts? See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question.

Comment: This is just $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_4$, isn't it?

Comment: @JLocke Try to compute powers of this matrices and products of this powers in different orders. Some patterns should emerge.

Comment: Ask a separate question now that the original question has an answer.

Comment: @lhf I am undecided about that. In theory you're right. But, at a certain level of studies I cannot quite nail down, the question would not have been asked if the group were abelian. Opinions differ to what extent the would-be-answerers need to cater for such things. I belong to the school that we should - if for no other reason than to maximize the amount of useful content.

Comment: Admittedly, the question does not offer much more content now that it has been edited to be about the group $Q_8$.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:*
Those two matrices commute, because the second one is $iI$.
Therefore, the group they generate is an abelian group.
What are the conjugacy classes of an abelian group?

Comment: This answer is no longer valid since the OP changed the second matrix.